# Как войти в систему не имея ни одной учётной записи включая Админ

Tags: windows, windows-10, администрирование

По случайности отключил все учётные записи, включая администратора =)

Теперь при входе в Админ учётку ( единственную ) не могу войти, так как она отключена и просит обратиться к админу ))
Подскажите, как быть? Есть лазейки какие-нибудь в windows 10 ?

P.S: При нажатие на F8 ничего не происходит

**Обновление**

Попробовал следующее:

Запустил установочный диск с виндой, дальше в помощь запустил командную строку:

ввёл `net user Администратор /active:yes` - Успешно)

Захожу после, и мне опять пишет, что Админка выключена

Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Сидя в дружной и тёплой компании, наткнулись на этот вопрос :) Поставили на свежекупленный ноутбук windows, удалили экаунты (надо сказать, админовский всё же не удаляется, он просто запрещается), перезагрузили.

В целом, исправить ситуацию оказалось просто. Три шага:

0. Запустить установочную флэшку, в процессе запуска нажать `Shift+F10` для запуска командной строки (можно и без флэшки, но не на всех дистрибутивах и системах это получается)
1. `net user Администратор /active:yes`  как и предлагал автор, затем перезагрузка
2. `net user vicont Ghbdtn123 /add`  добавили пользователя (пароль администратора был пустым)

После удаления флэшки и перезагрузки ноутбука вошли с указанными в пункте 2 логином и паролем.